# Inserir dados de um combobox em um SELECT

Tags: php, query, mysqli, combobox

Boa tarde!

Tenho o seguinte problema, tenho que retirar relatórios de um certo banco de dados onde eu devo selecionar funcionários específicos, os mesmo devem ser selecionados de uma combobox:

```html
<select name="usuario" id="usuario">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecione o Usuário</option>
    <option>funcionario 1</option>
    <option>funcionario 2</option>
    <option>funcionario 3</option>
    </select>
```

quero que ao selecionar um funcionário, ele seja enviado para a seguinte query:

```
($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE usuario='$funcionario';"))
```

Eu devo fazer isso com json?
agradecimentos antecipados.

Atualizando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#usuario").on("change", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url        : 'sql.php',
            type       : 'POST',
            cache      : false,
            dataType   : 'json',
            data       : { 'usuario' : $("#usuario").val() },
            error      : function(){
                alert('Erro ao tentar a ação!');
            },
            success    : function( dados ){ 
                console.log(dados);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<select name="usuario" id="usuario">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecione o Usuário</option>
    <option>funcionario 1</option>
    <option>funcionario 2</option>
    <option>funcionario 3</option>
    </select>
```

`

e o `SQL`:

```
$usuario = array("usuario" => array(array("codigo"=>"funcionario 1", "nome"=>"funcionario 1"), array("codigo" => "funcionario 2", "nome"=>"funcionario 2"), array("codigo"=>"funcionario 3","nome"=>"funcionario 3")));  

                    echo json_encode($usuario);

                    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE usuario='$usuario';"))
                    {
                            // exibir os registros se hÃ¡ registros para mostrar
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                            {
                                    // exibir registros em uma tabela

                                    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing=0 style=border-collapse: collapse bordercolor='#4B5AAB'>";


                                    // definir cabeÃ§alhos de tabela
                                   echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Data</th> <th>Hora de entrada</th> <th>Hora de saída</th> <th>Comentário</th>";



                                    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                    {
                                            // cria uma linha para cada registro
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->id) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->data) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->hora_entra) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->hora_saida) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->coment) . "</td>"; 
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                    }

                                    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Você precisa que faça a busca automático ou trocar de user. Ou irá precisar clicar em um botão para enviar?

Comment: Clicando em um botão, enviando para outra pagina provavelmente.

Answer (score 4):

Thiago o `HTML` está errado, nas tags `<option>` troque o atributo de `idfuncionario` para `value`.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#usuario").on("change", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url        : 'caminho_para_arquivo.php',
        type       : 'POST',
        dataType   : 'json',
        data       : ({ 'usuario' : $("#usuario").val() }),
        error      : function(){
            alert('Erro ao tentar a acao!');
        },
        success    : function( dados ){ 
            alert(dados);
        }
    });
});
});
```

e no arquivo .php vc coloque algo + ou - igual a isso:

**SQL**

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'vertrigo') or die('Falha na conexão!');  
mysql_select_db('novo');
$objDados = mysql_query('select codigo from usuario where codigo = "69";', $conn);      
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($objDados) ){
   array_push($arr, $row['codigo']); //isso inseri dados no final de um array.
}

print json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Ele está dando a msg de erro, qual seria a causa disso?

Comment: `if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE usuario='$_POST['usuario']';"))` ficaria dessa forma o `SQL`?

Comment: A duas coisas que vc precisa ver, uma é a `URL` para o arquivo esta indo, as vezes pode ser que o caminho esteja errado e outra coisa é verificar se a sua consulta esta funcionado corretamente. ah! na hora de retornar os dados inserir a variável com os dados dentro da função json_encode();

Comment: Ficaria dessa forma? 


    `$usuario = json_encode(array("usuario" => array(
  array("codigo" => "funcionario 1", "nome" => "funcionario 1"),
  array("codigo" => "funcionario 2", "nome" => "funcionario 2"),
  array("codigo" => "funcionario 3", "nome" => "funcionario 3"))));`

creio que o a `URL` esteja correto. ;(

Comment: Quase isso Thiago, na verdade vc instância esse Array a variável e passa ela como parâmetro. Assim: `$usuario = array(
    "usuario" => array(   
        array(
            "codigo" => "funcionario 1", 
            "nome"   => "funcionario 1"
        ),   
        array(
            "codigo" => "funcionario 2", 
            "nome"   => "funcionario 2"
        ),   
        array(
            "codigo" => "funcionario 3", 
            "nome"   => "funcionario 3"
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($usuario);`

Comment: bah, não consigo mesmo, vou atualizar a pergunta com o meu codigo.

Comment: Thiago, abra o inspetor de elementos do Firefox, vá a aba `Console` atualiza a página e faça todo o processo novamente e presta atenção qual é o erro que retorna no console e me envie

Comment: `POST sql.php` o resultado é esse.

Comment: Um momento estou testando aqui.

Answer (score 3):

É importante que você defina a id do usuário no elemento option quando construir o select HTML, dessa forma você poderá usar o evento change com o jQuery para fazer uma nova requisição toda vez que uma nova opção do select for selecionada. É mais recomendável sim que se utilize JSON.

**Pode ver um exemplo de como deveria postar seu código aqui:**

```js
$("#usuario").on('change', function(){
   var usuario = $("#usuario option:selected" );
    alert("http://meusite.com/api/v1/usuario?id=" + usuario.attr('idusuario'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="usuario" id="usuario">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecione o Usuário</option>
    <option idusuario="1">funcionario 1</option>
    <option idusuario="2">funcionario 2</option>
    <option idusuario="3">funcionario 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Codigo do Codepen

```js
/*
 Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery - May 27, 2013
 (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
 license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/ 

$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
          $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
      });

      $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
          $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
      });

      function getSelectedValue(id) {
           return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
      }

      $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
          var $clicked = $(e.target);
          if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
      });


      $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
        
          var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
              title = $(this).val() + ",";
        
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
              $('.multiSel').append(html);
              $(".hida").hide();
          } 
          else {
              $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
              var ret = $(".hida");
              $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);
              
          }
      });
```

```css
body {  
    font: normal 14px/100% "Andale Mono", AndaleMono, monospace;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #374954;
  
} 
a {
    color:#fff;
}
.dropdown dd, .dropdown dt {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.dropdown ul {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}
.dropdown dd {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown a, 
.dropdown a:visited {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.dropdown dt a {
    background-color:#4F6877;
    display:block;
    padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
    min-height: 25px;
    line-height: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:0;
    width:272px;
}
.dropdown dt a span, .multiSel span {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 3px 2px 0;
}
.dropdown dd ul {
    background-color: #4F6877;
    border:0;
    color:#fff;
    display:none;
    left:0px;
    padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    width:280px;
    list-style:none;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.dropdown span.value {
    display:none;
}
.dropdown dd ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
}
.dropdown dd ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#fff;
}
button {
  background-color: #6BBE92;
  width: 302px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dropdown"> 
  
    <dt>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="hida">Select</span>    
      <p class="multiSel"></p>  
    </a>
    </dt>
  
    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />HTC</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson" />Sony Ericson</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" />Motorola</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
  <button>Filter</button>
</dl>
```

```js
   /*
Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery - May 27, 2013
(c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/ 

$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });

  $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });

  function getSelectedValue(id) {
       return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
  }

  $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
      var $clicked = $(e.target);
      if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });


  $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
    
      var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
          title = $(this).val() + ",";
    
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
          $('.multiSel').append(html);
          $(".hida").hide();
      } 
      else {
          $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
          var ret = $(".hida");
          $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);
          
      }
  });
```

```html
   <dl class="dropdown"> 
  
<dt>
<a href="#">
  <span class="hida">Select</span>    
  <p class="multiSel"></p>  
</a>
</dt>
  
<dd>
    <div class="mutliSelect">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />HTC</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson" />Sony Ericson</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" />Motorola</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</dd>
  <button>Filter</button>
</dl>
```